# How can I use $ _SERVER ["REQUEST_URI"] to take the path of the server that I have mounted in PHP?

Tags: php, session, web, server, apache2

I want to use the variable `$_SERVER ["REQUEST_URI"]` to get the url of my mounted server, but I get the 404 error:

For example:

```
www.example.com/dir/
```

I need that path to take it as the `index.php` and from there I take the routes I need, but for this error I can not get the values ​​I require.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this..

```
//get the url
$myaddress = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//parse the url
$parse_url = parse_url($address);

//use explode to get the path
$paths = explode('/', ltrim($parse_url['path'], '/'));


print_r($paths);
// or get the first path
echo $paths['0'];
```

You have now the path..